# islower() for strings - Python

Tags: python, string, function

I am doing some Python self-study (very beginner) and am stumped on this exercise I've been given - meant to check if a string has any lower case letters:

```
def is_lower(word):
    for x in word:
        if x.islower():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

`is_lower("Cat")` returns `False`

`is_lower("cAt")` returns `True`

and `is_lower("caT")` returns `True`

I'm not sure why I am getting these differences - it appears to only be testing the first letter of the word, and I'm not sure why. I thought it should be iterating through each letter of the word, since its a for loop

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep looping until you read all the characters.

```
for x in word:
    if x.islower():
        # We found *one* lower case letter, so return True
        return True
# We found *no* lower case letters, so return False
return False
```

Or, you can simplify:

```
return any(x.islower() for x in word)
```

Comment: If you really want to simplify, why not do `word.islower()`?

Comment: @ekhumoro that would return `True` if **all** characters are lowercase, OP wants to return `True` if **any** character is lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

On the first time you go through that loop, you either hit the if statement, which returns True, or the else statement, which returns False. You never get to the second character.

```
def is_lower(word):

    for x in word:
        if x.islower():
            #Found a lowercase letter!
            return True
    #Okay, now we're done with the for loop.
    #We have not encountered any lower case letters
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You return directly out of your function on the first loop. What you are saying is

1. Loop through all the letters

   1. Check if this letter is lowercase
   2. We're done! Return that value

What you probably want to do instead is

```
for x in word:
    if x.islower():
        return True
else:
    return False
```

This will look for the first letter that if lowercase and any are found it will return True

Comment: This implements the wrong logic. It checks if **all** characters are lowercase, OP wants to check if **any** character is lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

This has all to do with the programming control flow.
When a function hits a return statement, it will stop the function and return the value back to where the function is called.

for the word `Cat`, you will loop true to words one by one using the `for x in word:`statement, you start by checking the first letter `C`, which is not lower, so it returns `False` the function stops and the other letters are not checked.

the same happens for the word `cAt`, it checks the first letter a `c`which is lower case, the `return True` is reached and the function stops.

Instead use a function that is build up like:

```
for x in word:
    if x.islower():
        return True
return False
```

here each letter will be checked if it's lower or not, if one of them is lower it will return True. Only at the very end when none of the letters is lower it will return False.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a one-liner:

```
print True if any(x.islower() for x in word) else False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_lower(word):
    for x in word:
        if x.islower():
            return True
    return False
```

should do the trick. Basically, loop through all letters, if any is lowercase, return True (and thus exit the whole function). If you haven't returned by the end of the for loop, return False.